# Insert 'NULL' From CSV Attaching Unwanted Single Quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day. I have a query that grabs data from a csv and inserts it into a table. However, there are nulls in the csv and when the insert happens, the insertion appends a single quote before and after the word `'NULL'`. I used the `KEEPNULLS` but am still having issues.

I would prefer not to call out every column and inject a coalesce or something where I change it from `NULL` to something else then back to `NULL` again. The number of columns in the table will eventually grow and I would like to not have to change anything in this script.

Any way to insert data into a table from a csv that has NULLs in it without the single quotes attaching to it? Thanks for the help.

Script to Retrieve and insert data from csv

```
TRUNCATE TABLE jj 

BULK INSERT jj 
  FROM 'F:\NewHorizon\ExportSubObjGroup.csv' 
  WITH 
    ( 
      datafiletype = 'char', 
      fieldterminator = ',', 
      keepnulls 
    )
```

Table I want to insert data into

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jj](
    [pkid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [mo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [pr] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [pri] [bigint] NULL,
    [vis] [int] NULL,
    [sys] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [are] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [equ] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [dev] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [fiee] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [syst] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [areaPr] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [equipPr] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [devicePr] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [attr] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [grou] [bigint] NULL,
    [eventi] [bigint] NULL,
    [numid] [bigint] NULL,
    [dataType] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [typeCol] [int] NULL,
    [boolVal] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [greaterThan] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [greaterEqThan] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lessThan] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lessEqThan] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [equalTo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [note] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [durat] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [groupi] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [plcTagC] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [eventidC] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [fnC] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_groupings45] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pkid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The DATA from csv

```
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,PH,NULL,NULL,SYSTEM_IO,DI_MCR,3001,1,3001,NULL,0,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,PH,NULL,NULL,SYSTEM_IO,DI_MCR_CP,3002,2,3002,NULL,0,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,PH,NULL,NULL,SYSTEM_IO,DI_MCR_CP,3003,3,3003,NULL,0,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

The results in table jj

```
1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   PH  'NULL'  'NULL'  SYSTEM_IO   DI_MCR  3001    1   3001    'NULL'  0   1   'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'
2   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   PH  'NULL'  'NULL'  SYSTEM_IO   DI_MCR_CP   3002    2   3002    'NULL'  0   1   'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'
3   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   PH  'NULL'  'NULL'  SYSTEM_IO   DI_MCR_CP   3003    3   3003    'NULL'  0   1   'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'  'NULL'
```

Comment: How about replacing ,NULL, with the empty value (,,) in your input CSV file?

Comment: @vatsal Hey if I do that then I have to call out every column. If I add more columns in the futures I have to go back to this script and include those columns. Would prefer if I didnt have to do that

Comment: Can you just find/replace all instances of the string literal `NULL` with an empty string? Write a little script which pre-procesess the incoming CSV before loading it into SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either update the file before it goes in to replace it with '' or you can update the table post import with

```
  Update table
  Set column = NULL 
  where column = 'NULL'
```

Here's an update script you can execute as part of your post import job. This took me 5 minutes to write in excel and paste it here

```
UPDATE table SET[mo]=NULL WHERE [mo]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[pr]=NULL WHERE [pr]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[pri]=NULL WHERE [pri]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[vis]=NULL WHERE [vis]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[sys]=NULL WHERE [sys]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[are]=NULL WHERE [are]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[equ]=NULL WHERE [equ]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[dev]=NULL WHERE [dev]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[fiee]=NULL WHERE [fiee]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[syst]=NULL WHERE [syst]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[areaPr]=NULL WHERE [areaPr]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[equipPr]=NULL WHERE [equipPr]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[devicePr]=NULL WHERE [devicePr]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[attr]=NULL WHERE [attr]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[grou]=NULL WHERE [grou]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[eventi]=NULL WHERE [eventi]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[numid]=NULL WHERE [numid]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[dataType]=NULL WHERE [dataType]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[typeCol]=NULL WHERE [typeCol]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[boolVal]=NULL WHERE [boolVal]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[greaterThan]=NULL WHERE [greaterThan]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[greaterEqThan]=NULL WHERE [greaterEqThan]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[lessThan]=NULL WHERE [lessThan]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[lessEqThan]=NULL WHERE [lessEqThan]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[equalTo]=NULL WHERE [equalTo]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[note]=NULL WHERE [note]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[durat]=NULL WHERE [durat]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[groupi]=NULL WHERE [groupi]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[plcTagC]=NULL WHERE [plcTagC]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[eventidC]=NULL WHERE [eventidC]='NULL'
UPDATE table SET[fnC]=NULL WHERE [fnC]='NULL'
```

Comment: Agreed. OP could also do a script of select * into #tempcleanup from table where columns = 'NULL' then clean it up and put it back in again.

Comment: I almost always import to a staging table so I can clean the data up before putting it into the final table(s).  That way I don't have to mess with the pure source and don't have to have anything inconsistent in the final table(s). (external sources are fickle enough, at least if I can dump it into a staging area first, I can cut out a lot of uncertainty)

Comment: I guess the KEEPNULLs does something different than what I intended it for. @Isaiah your way about the post import and an update seems the best go around..... This is also in a staging table... But exporting to a csv is easy. Its a select * and your done. Importing is difficult with nulls. Either way, if I add a column I need to add it in the script. So this way works. Just thought there as an a nice way of doing it without calling each column